hcitool info is not working for all BTLE devices
Hi I'm experiencing inconsistent behavior with hcitool.
When I try to run hcitool info <BD_ADDR> I get the following error:
can't create connection: Input/output error
I have also tried running sdptool browse <BD_ADDR> and get the following error:
Failed to connect to SDP server on <BD_ADDR>: Host is down
Now when I try this on my Airpods or iPhone I can get information, but for other devices like a BTLE speaker I get these errors.
I am just trying to understand this disparity and if there are other methods to communicate with these devices using command line tools or other tools?
I am not too familiar with BTLE technology so would also like to know if there is a specific configuration that prevents these tools for gaining information from the device.
Thanks.
I tried looking up other commands that may help but didn't find anything much.

hcitool, and sdptool were deprecated by the BlueZ project in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses them, there is a chance that it might be out of date. This is the steps required: https://askubuntu.com/a/1323766

@ukBaz if that's the case then why does it work for certain Bluetooth devices and not others?  I would think it would not work across the board.  I feel like this behavior I am experiencing is more directly linked with BTLE technology and wanted to know if anyone has deep insight on what it is and how I can confirm it?
